# get update tuple value in list based on condition

Tags: scala

I have list like below -

```
val tpList = List((1,"Sachin",2),(2,"Rahul",3.50),(3,"dravid",5.75),(4,"kohli",4.56),(5,"dhoni",7.50))
```

From this I want to extract each tuple and multiply rating by .5 if rating is more than 5.

Can some one tell me how to achieve this

Here `(1,"Sachin,2)---(rownum,name,rating)` -

Comment: You want to remove ratings that are bellow `5` or just do not multiply them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use filter and then map.

```
val data:List[(Int, String, Double)] =  List((1,"Sachin",2),(2,"Rahul",3.50),(3,"dravid",5.75),(4,"kohli",4.56),(5,"dhoni",7.50))

val filterdata = data.filter(_._3 > 5).map(x => (x._1,x._2,x._3*0.5))

print(filterdata) /* output: List((3,dravid,11.5), (5,dhoni,15.0)) */
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert names to upper case? If it is can you tell me how to do that. We can get by passing .toUpperCase. But I am not sure where to add in this syntax.

Comment: I have added val filterdata = data.filter(_._3 > 5).map(x => (x._1,x._2,x._3*0.5) && x.toUppercase) But it is throwing error

Comment: yes. data.filter(_._3 > 5).map(x => (x._1,x._2.toUpperCase,x._3*0.5)) should do. Adding && adds another condition.

Comment: great. It is working

Answer (score 1):

The below should work

```
val tpList: List[(Int, String, Double)] = List((1,"Sachin",2),(2,"Rahul",3.50),(3,"dravid",5.75),(4,"kohli",4.56),(5,"dhoni",7.50))
```

You can do map

```
 println(tpList.map(x => x.copy(_3 = if (x._3 > 5) x._3 * 0.5 else x._3)))
```

or you can use collect

```
 println(tpList.collect { case (x,y, z)  => (x,y, if (z >5) z* 0.5 else z)} )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this (as I understand, all items that their rating <= 5 should left unchanged):

```
val tpList: List[(Int,String,Double)] = List((1,"Sachin",2),(2,"Rahul",3.50),(3,"dravid",5.75),(4,"kohli",4.56),(5,"dhoni",7.50))

val result = tpList.map{
  case (x,y,rating) if (rating > 5) => (x,y,rating*0.5)
  case rest => rest
} 

// result = List((1,Sachin,2), (2,Rahul,3.5), (3,dravid,2.875), (4,kohli,4.56), (5,dhoni,3.75))
```